# MongoLab Connection with swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to connect to mongolab service in my swift app using DB user name and password instead of mongoAPI key? please help me with this.

Comment: i would not recommend that direct connection from client side(swift) and your db

Comment: mongoAPI key is the only way to use mongolab service?

Comment: yes only with api key, you can you this [library](https://github.com/ustwo/mongolabkit-swift)

Comment: @PratibhaShetty we recommend that users create their own REST API that sits on top of their MongoDB database. Using the mLab REST API isn't appropriate for serious mobile apps, because a user could decompile the app and find your API key.